# dynamic jasper osgi bundle

Tags: jasper-reports, osgi, dynamic-jasper, eclipse-virgo

I am trying to use *DynamicJasper* in an osgi environment ( Virgo ), I have not found a osgied *DynamicJasper* bundle, and when I tried to create one myself using *maven-bundle-plugin* that includes *JasperReports* and *DynamicJasper*, I keep on getting this error:

```
d:\virgo\DynamicReport_1339161554051_414506.java:4: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;

d:\virgo\DynamicReport_1339161554051_414506.java:5: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.*;

d:\virgo\DynamicReport_1339161554051_414506.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol: class JREvaluator
public class DynamicReport_1339161554051_414506 extends JREvaluator
```

Is there an existing *DynamicJasper* bundle in an open repository somewhere? Has anyone managed to create such a bundle successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding:

Import-Bundle: com.springsource.org.apache.commons.digester;version="[1.8.0,2.0.0)"

Comment: I'm gettng the same error using plain jasperreports? Where did you add the import-bundle?